# Splitting a string into 2-letter segments

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, iterator

I have a string, which I need to split into 2-letter pieces. For example, `'ABCDXY'` should become `['AB', 'CD', 'XY']`. The behavior in the case of odd number of characters may be entirely arbitrary (I'll check the length in advance).

Is there any way to do this without an ugly loop?

Comment: Hey mate... what do you mean by "ugly loop"? XD

Comment: I didn't think about it. But now that I did... An ugly loop is a loop that is uglier than necessary, or that is present when no loop is really required :)

Comment: related: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
>>> [s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
['AB', 'CD', 'XY']
```

Comment: thats a loop. OP said "no loops"

Comment: He did say "without an ugly loop"... and this certainly avoids that. :-)

Comment: Maybe that's the only way. I guess sometimes loops are required.

Comment: Well, I understand it in the way "not a standard for loop", I was supposing list comprehensions would be good. Let's see what the OP says... :-)

Comment: List comprehensions are almost not a loop, so this would qualify :)

Comment: And this turned out to be faster than either of the regex approaches.

Answer (score 16):

Using regular expressions!

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "ABCDXYv"
>>> re.findall(r'.{1,2}',s,re.DOTALL)
['AB', 'CD', 'XY', 'v']
```

---

I know it has been a while, but I came back to this and was curious about which method was better; mine: `r'.{1,2}'` or Jon's `r'..?'`. On the surface, Jon's looks much nicer, and I thought it would be much faster than mine, but I was surprised to find otherwise, so I thought I would share:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer("re.findall(r'.{1,2}', 'ABCDXYv')", setup='import re').repeat()
[1.9064299485802252, 1.8369554649334674, 1.8548105833383772]
>>> timeit.Timer("re.findall(r'..?', 'ABCDXYv')", setup='import re').repeat()
[1.9142223469651611, 1.8670038395145383, 1.85781945659771]
```

Which shows that indeed `r'.{1,2}'` is the better/faster choice. (But only slightly)

Comment: Careful, this fails to work correctly if the string contains newlines.

Comment: @TimPietzcker you are right, i will add that with the flag to handle such a case.

Comment: `()` are unnecessary in the regex: `re.findall('(?s)..', s)`

Comment: `or take the last character in the string and add that to your list at the end.` -- `def grouper()` seems a bit convoluted - the regex can just be `.{1,2}`

Comment: You could use `..?` as the regex.

Comment: @JanneKarila They could - but that's my answer ;)

Comment: @JonClements good idea with {1,2} i dunno why i didnt think of that. will edit to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
s = 'ABCDEFG'
r = [s[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(s), 2)]

# r is ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'G']
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you don't care about odd chars, you could use a regex (avoiding the loop):

```
s = 'ABCDEFG'
r = re.compile('(..)').findall(s)
# r is ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing ugly about the perfectly Pythonic:

```
string = 'ABCDXY'
[string[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(string), 2)]
```

You could also use the following (from - http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

(Which depending how you look at it - may or may not be using 'loops' ;))

or something like:

```
re.findall('..?', string)
```

Comment: +1 for the zip solution, which none of these other answers mentioned. It actually returns `[(str, str), (str, str), ...]` though, not `[str, str, ...]`, so it would take more code to make it useful.

Comment: Also, handiest bastardized use of regexes I've ever seen! I like yours the best because it handles odd lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, this one built on `zip` and a slice stride:

```
map(''.join, itertools.izip_longest(mystr[::2], mystr[1::2], fillvalue=''))
```

It does handle odd-length inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a yet another solution without explicit loops (though [@Emmanuel's answer is the most appropriate for your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491575/4279)):

```
s = 'abcdef'
L = zip(s[::2], s[1::2])
# -> [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
```

To get strings:

```
print map(''.join, L)
# ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

On Python 3 wrap using `list()` where necessary.

Comment: jinx! we were both thinking `zip` at the same time