# How to split an integer into pairs of integers assigned to a variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic encryption (yes i know it's unsafe etc). I need to split up a random integer into pairs. I'd like to have each pair assigned to a variable.
For example:

```
digits = 12345678
```

Should be split up into

```
pair1 = 12
pair2 = 34
pair3 = 56
pair4 = 78
```

How do I do that? (I'm new to coding so please ELI5)

Comment: You could convert to string and use indexing. Or use division/mod: `12345678 % 100 = 78`....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string into 2-letter segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491537/splitting-a-string-into-2-letter-segments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def splitInt(integer, interval=2):
    integer = str(integer)
    newList = []
    for ditget in range(0, len(integer), interval):
        newList.append(int(integer[ditget:ditget + interval]))
    return newList
```

Answer (score 0):

Stringy solution:

```
s = str(1234567890)

def processing(s):
  i=0
  while i < len(s):
    yield s[i:i+2]
    i = i+2

[x for x in processing(s)]
```

Output:

['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']

If you want it as a string with spaces separating the integer pairs:

```
" ".join([x for x in processing(s)])
```